# 0-100 number range regex excluding 1 and 3

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression that can detect any given number in the range of `0` to `100` excluding `1` and `3`.

Example of valid numbers:

```
0, 2, 4, 6,13, 23 80, 99, 100
```

Numbers that should fail:

```
1, 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to exclude specifically number `1` and `3`. I suppose that `10`, `13` and `31` for instance would still be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Detect any given number in the range of 0 to 100 , however excluding 1 and 3

```
^(?!(?:1|3)$)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ6zH0/1)

In case the numbers are not standalone strings:

```
\b(?!(?:1|3)\b)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ6zH0/2)

The main point here is a [*look-ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the beginning, [*anchors*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`\b` word boundary, `^` start and `$` end of string) and the [*character classes*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) with [*limiting quantifiers*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

The `(?!(?:1|3)$)` lookahead makes sure the match fails if a `1` or ([`|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) `3` appears right after the start of string (`^`) and before the end of string (`$`) (or between word boundaries as in the second example).

The `[0-9]{1,2}` character class matches 1 or 2 digits (due to a limiting quantifier `{1,2}`) from `0` to `9`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I am really new to regex and was not able to use the look-ahead feature.

Comment: Hi,  the above expression is actually a part of a more generic expression, where, it is combined with some more string literals.                             `Regular Expression :  (?!(?:1|3)\b)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)_[YN]_(?!(?:1|3)\b)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)_[YN]_[YN]`                                                                  So for this expression, what my success result should be is : `Sucess 4_N_2_Y_Y' and                                                                             `Failure :1_N_2_Y_Y`    , However even this is coming as success.

Comment: Try [`(?!(?:1|3)_)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)_[YN]_(?!(?:1|3)_)(?:[0-9]{1,2}|100)_[YN]_[YN]`](https://regex101.com/r/gZ6zH0/3). `\b` won't work because `_` is considered a word character by the regex engine.

Comment: cool !! I need to start from scratch.